# Streaming a split pdf using ITextSharp to store it in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, webforms, stream, itext

I am using ITextSharp to split a pdf into multiple pdfs.
At the moment I have managed to copy the file locally.

Ideally I would like to stream it directly to Azure, and if I cannot do it in one step, copy the file locally, the stream to azure and delete the local file.

However I have trouble to write the file to a stream. I have tried many different ways, but with no luck.

Below is the code.

If you can help me, thank you in advance.

```
        foreach(DTO.QRCodeInfo q in Q)
    {
//q.ScriptPath=C:\WEB APPLICATIONS\ADMIN-Platform\AppData\/0002-00003/A-0002-00001-00003.pdf
//qi.MasterPath=C:\WEB APPLICATIONS\ADMIN-Platform\AppData\/0002-00003\MD-0002-00003-001-QRCode Sample.pdf

        q.ScriptPath = qi.Container + q.FileName;
        reader = new PdfReader(qi.MasterPath);
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        sourceDocument = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(q.PageStart));
        pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(sourceDocument, new System.IO.FileStream(q.ScriptPath, System.IO.FileMode.Create)); //Create file in Azure

        sourceDocument.Open();

        //split pdf into student script
        for (int i = q.PageStart; i <= q.PageEnd; i++)
        {
            importedPage = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
            pdfCopyProvider.AddPage(importedPage);
        }

        sourceDocument.Close();
        reader.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you finish with each file, convert into a Byte array and then upload from stream.

```
        static string storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=MYACCOUNT;AccountKey=MYKEY";
    static string azureFolderPath = "rootFolder/subFolder";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("websites");
        CloudBlobDirectory cloudBlobDirectory = container.GetDirectoryReference(azureFolderPath);

        //get source file to split
        string pdfFile = "SOURCE.pdf";
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob1 = cloudBlobDirectory.GetBlockBlobReference(pdfFile);

        //convert to memory stream
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        blockBlob1.DownloadToStream(memStream);

        //create reader from memory stream
        PdfReader sourcePDF = new PdfReader(memStream.ToArray());

        //Console.WriteLine(sourcePDF.NumberOfPages);

        //get source file to split
        for (var i = 1; i <= sourcePDF.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            //define output file for azure
            string outputPDFFile = "output" + i + ".pdf";
            CloudBlockBlob outputblockBlob = cloudBlobDirectory.GetBlockBlobReference(outputPDFFile);

            //create new document
            MemoryStream newPDFStream = new MemoryStream();
            var pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            var pdf = new PdfCopy(pdfDoc, newPDFStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            PdfImportedPage currentPage = pdf.GetImportedPage(sourcePDF, i);

            pdf.AddPage(currentPage);
            pdfDoc.Close();

            //upload to azure
            Byte[] content = newPDFStream.ToArray();

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(content))
            {
                outputblockBlob.UploadFromStream(ms);
            }
        }
        sourcePDF.Close();
    }
```